# $setPrinstine: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at r (main.min.js:29)
    at Object.f [as makeDefault] (main.min.js:29)
    at makeDefault (main.min.js:29)
    at Object.s [as resetElement] (main.min.js:29)
    at u.$setPristine (main.min.js:29)
    at main.min.js:10
    at o (main.min.js:8)
    at _e.s.$setPristine (main.min.js:10)
    at l.ListenersCtrl.e.clearForm (dashboard.min.js:13)
    at main.min.js:10
```

added line like `this.form.$setPrinstine()`

Comment: please provide more detail and a question mark

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use `$scope`:

```
$scope.form.$setPrinstine()
```

if you are minifying your script file then make sure to use the controller this way:

```
myapp.controller(['$scope', demoCtrl])

function demoCtrl($scope){}
```